# Mysql query : join and sort

Tags: mysql, sorting, join

i'm still learning...i have two database tables

```
setting: id, uid, deptid
user :  id, uid, name
```

i want the result to be sort ascending by name from user table

```
$result = $DB->query("SELECT s.*, u.* FROM ".$myDB->prefix("setting")." AS s LEFT JOIN ".$myDB->prefix("user")." AS u ON s.uid=u.uid ORDER BY u.name ASC");
```

please advice..Thank you

Comment: The following answer will give you all you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/967853

Comment: Why would a user have both an id and a uid?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT setting.*, user.* FROM setting LEFT JOIN user ON setting.uid = user.uid ORDER BY user.name ASC
```

Also, [look in to which join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) you'll want to be using to get the right data. The venn diagrams on these pages easily represent what data will be shown.

In my experience, it's usually the Inner join I look at working with.